# How to include license for MIT-licensed CSS?

Tags: licensing, open-source

I have a project licensed under the GPL. However, it includes a bit of code from [animate.css](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css), which uses the MIT license. How would I include the appropriate licensing information for that CSS? I've included that bit of css (maybe 25 or so lines) in my main stylesheet, so I'd rather not have a huge stamp like what's on [this page](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT), if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IANAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANAL), but instead of putting the whole license terms in your your CSS it's often common to put just its name and a link to the full termsso something like this would do:

```
/* Licensed under the MIT/X11 License (http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT) */
```

Plus, as your project is GPL and you're forced to redistribute the whole source anyways, you'll have your own code-repository or code archive somewhere, in which you could have a LICENSE or CONTRIBUTING text file containing the licensing terms for your app (GPL) and dependencies (here the MIT/X11 for that bit of CSS). That's a pretty common way to go about things.

Another good example to follow (but here with GPL and MIT instead of ASL or what have you) is outlined in the [Apache Foundation](http://www.apache.org/) [Developer's Guide](http://www.apache.org/dev/) section on **[Assembling Licenses](http://www.apache.org/dev/licensing-howto.html)**.

Answer (score 2):

> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
>   all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

So... You must include it *somehow*.

Definitely leave the `(c) copyright 2014 So-and-So`, it's that person's hard work after all.

Then you can link the MIT licensing information by just adding a url to it. Just make sure that the license is available and that link doesn't go down. I'd recommend just putting the license in a .txt file on your server so you know it's available.

Answer (score 0):

You main stylesheet is GPL, GPL requires whole derived work to be covered by GPL and MIT allows it. So you just mention the source, but I don't think you need to include the license since it does not apply anyway. Besides 25 lines is unlikely to be considered substantial portion anyway.